# A weak version of Brouwer's Theorem

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Let $A : \Bbb{R}^n\longrightarrow \Bbb{R}^n$ be an affine map and let $X\subseteq \Bbb{R}^n$ be a compact convex set which is invariant under $A$. I want to show that $A$ has a fixed point in $X$.

**REMARK** Of course this can be done using Brouwer's Theorem. But I am looking for elementary proofs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\pi_r \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ the coordinate projection. Let $m_r(K) = \min \{ \pi_r(x) : x \in K\}$ and $M_r(K) = \max \{ \pi_r(x) : x \in K\}$ for any compact nonempty $K$. Let $X_0 = X$, and for $1 \leqslant r \leqslant n$, let $X_r = \{ x \in X_{r-1} : \pi_r(A(x)) = \pi_r(x)\}$. Since $A$ is continuous, each $X_r$ is closed in $X_{r-1}$, hence compact, and since $A$ is affine, each $X_r$ is convex. It remains to see that $X_{r-1} \neq \varnothing \Rightarrow X_r \neq \varnothing$.

Let $\varphi_r(x) = \pi_r(A(x)) - \pi_r(x)$. On $X_{r-1} \cap \pi_r^{-1}(m_r(X_{r-1}))$, we have $\varphi_r \geqslant 0$, and on $X_{r-1} \cap \pi_r^{-1}(M_r(X_{r-1}))$ we have $\varphi_r \leqslant 0$. Since $\varphi_r$ is continuous and $X_{r-1}$ connected, $X_r = X_{r-1} \cap \varphi_r^{-1}(0) \neq \varnothing$.

$X_n$ is the set of fixed points of $A$ in $X$.